# Dredd verification response body and headers

Tags: rest, dredd

I have similar openapi.yml spec file:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
    title: some title
    version: "4"
paths:
    /users/{userId}/data:
        get:
            summary: some summary
            description: some description
            operationId: userData
            parameters:
                - name: some-token
                  in: header
                  description: desc
                  required: true
                  schema:
                      type: string
                  example: "tokenExample"
                
                ...
                - name: userId
                  in: path
                  description: desc
                  required: true
                  schema:
                      type: string
                  example: "someID"
            responses:
                "200":
                    description: desc
                    content:
                        "application/json":
                            schema:
                                $ref: '#/components/schemas/DataModel'

components:
    schemas:
        DataModel:
            type: object
            properties:
                data1:
                    type: integer
                    format: int32
                data2:
                    type: integer
                    format: int32
                data3:
                    type: integer
                    format: int32
```

Test execution giving me such result:

```bash
request: 
method: GET
uri: /users/<someID>/data
headers: 
    some-token: 389fe056-e904-48fd-8d89-caaf8769ab84
    ...
    User-Agent: Dredd/14.0.0 (Linux 5.10.104-linuxkit; x64)

body: 



expected: 
headers: 
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

body: 
{
  "data1": 0,
  "data2": 0,
  "data3": 0
}
statusCode: 200


actual: 
statusCode: 200
headers: 
    server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
    set-cookie: rememberMe=deleteMe; Path=/somepath; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 17-Nov-2022 08:41:46 GMT; Secure
    content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
    transfer-encoding: chunked
    date: Fri, 18 Nov 2022 08:41:46 GMT
    connection: close

bodyEncoding: utf-8
body: 
{
  "data1": 0,
  "data2": 0,
  "data3": 0
}
```

Body and status code matched perfectly, but something, maybe headers, failing verification. How can I get passed verification for this test? Is headers matching necessary for passing test? If yes, how achieve headers matching?

PS. I now that is very [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70956400/how-to-set-up-dredd-to-ignore-headers-in-the-assertion) already on Stackoverflow, but it was asked pretty long time ago, so I decided to refresh it and some more details.

Answer (score 0):

Running `dredd` with debug log level (--logLevel=debug) helped me to recognize the problem. That needed to be exactly `"application/json;charset=utf-8"` in content response, instead of `"application/json"`